# SQL query to find expenditures of employees who have exceeded their limit

Tags: sql, mysql

I've 2 tables `emp` and `expenditure`.

**Emp:**

> ID, NAME

**Expenditure:**

> ID, EMP_ID, AMOUNT

Each emp has a limit of 100 that he/she can spend. We want to check which emp has expenditure > 100.

Output attributes needed: *Emp name, exp id, amount*

**My query:**

```
SELECT E.NAME,
    EXP.ID,
    EXP.AMOUNT
FROM EMP E
INNER JOIN expenditure EXP ON E.ID = EXP.EMP_ID
WHERE E.ID in
        (SELECT EMP_ID
            FROM
                (SELECT EMP_ID,
                        SUM(AMOUNT) AS TOTAL
                    FROM expenditure
                    GROUP BY EMP_ID
                    HAVING SUM(AMOUNT) > 100.00
                    ORDER BY TOTAL DESC) SUBQ)
ORDER BY EXP.AMOUNT desc;
```

Is it possible to optimize this?  Can the subqueries be simplified?

Comment: Where does `T.AMOUNT` come from? Does this query work?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware. typo.. updated question.

Comment: This question has been [posted on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71545941/reduce-number-of-subqueries). I think that's where it belongs, and I voted to close it for that reason.

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: I think this is (basically) on-topic for CodeReview, since it's asking for optimization; though OP should show the full table definitions.

Comment: The `ORDER BY TOTAL DESC` in the subquery is useless.

Comment: What does optimization mean? Increase readability, increase performance, reduce number of lines of code?

Comment: Please note the 3 rules of posting [SQL questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sql): "1) Provide context, 2) Include the schema, 3) If asking about performance, include indexes and the output of EXPLAIN SELECT."

Answer (score 9):

Let's assume that your table declarations look like this and that you're using MySQL 8.0:

```sql
create table Employee(
    id serial primary key,
    name text not null
);

create table Expenditure(
    id serial primary key,
    employee_id int not null references Employee(id)
        on update cascade on delete cascade,
    amount decimal not null check(amount > 0)
);
```

(PostgreSQL would allow for the [standards-compliant](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/features-sql-standard.html) `generated always as identity` as well as a `money` column; MySQL supports neither.)

With your test data as

```sql
insert into Employee(name) values
   ('Bob'),
   ('Doug'),
   ('McKenzie');
   
insert into Expenditure(employee_id, amount)
select id, amount from (
    select 9 as amount
    union all select 2
    union all select 3
    union all select 5
) as amounts
cross join Employee where name = 'Bob';
   
insert into Expenditure(employee_id, amount)
select id, amount from (
    select 100 as amount
    union all select 190
    union all select 450
) as amounts
cross join Employee where name = 'Doug';
```

PostgreSQL would allow for the standard `values`-subquery syntax, which MySQL does not:

```sql
insert into Expenditure(employee_id, amount)
select id, amount from (
    values (9), (2), (3), (5)
) as amounts(amount)
cross join Employee where name = 'Bob';
   
insert into Expenditure(employee_id, amount)
select id, amount from (
    values (100), (190), (450)
) as amounts(amount)
cross join Employee where name = 'Doug';
```

You can eliminate some of your subqueries and your `in` clause by using a windowing expression:

```sql
select exp.employee_id, emp.name, exp.amount
from Employee emp
join (
    select
        employee_id, amount,
        sum(amount) over (partition by employee_id) as total
    from Expenditure
) exp on exp.employee_id = emp.id
where exp.total >= 100
order by exp.amount desc;
```

You will always need at least one `join` to get between your employee and expense tables. [See fiddle.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iHomQGwJDf1ro1wLh6NZwA/0)

All of that said, the windowing syntax is a little bit unwieldy, and you can also do (vaguely closer to your original query)

```sql
select exp.employee_id, emp.name, exp.amount
from Employee emp
join Expenditure exp on exp.employee_id = emp.id
where exp.employee_id in (
    select employee_id
    from Expenditure
    group by employee_id
    having sum(amount) >= 100
)
order by exp.amount desc;
```

but with only one subquery and one `sum()` expression.

Comment: "MySQL is a toy RDBMS" I am no fan of mysql, but this seems unnecessary

Comment: It’s not if it’s true and adds value to the answer which IMO it does

Comment: This is a bread and butter problem, and windowing is totally peacocking. Yes the subquery (and there should be only one) can be simplified. Why the nesting? Why the sorting? Nothing tricky required. In fact it should be an ANSI join for readability.

Comment: MySQL is definitely not a toy. It also has window functions, you answer seems to imply that it doesn't.

Comment: One more thing: the `::` (casting) operator is not standard, it can only be used in Postgres. Why is it in the answer?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ The standards comment wasn't clear enough and has been moved up. I also found a different fiddle site that supports 8.0 so I've switched to that for clarity. MySQL is absolutely a toy and doesn't take itself seriously - perhaps not a surprise when it was bought out by one of its competitors.

Comment: @Reinderien how is what you think of mysql relevant to the answer? It is used professionally by many people (rightly or wrongly), disqualifying it as a toy is not helpful. Glad to see you edited it out

Comment: Additionally, mysql does have a `values` syntax

Comment: And mysql also has syntax for Identity

Comment: @Reinderien just wondering: why did you change fiddle site? dbfiddle.uk does support MySQL 8 (and MariaDB 10) among many others. I like it especially because it has so many different DBMS and makes it easy to compare code between them.

Comment: @HoneyBadger actually MySQL only supports the `INSERT ... VALUES ...` syntax, not the full version as in the answer here (`... from (
    values (9), (2), (3), (5)
) as amounts(amount) ...`)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ it's not really relevant to my point, but I also saw the `values row()` syntax (or similar). Either way, there's no point mentioning it in the answer, which was my point